# google apps script formula

Tags: google-apps-script

I'd like to open some tables I created in Google Apps as a form. Because of some reasons, the form should open itself by opening the table without clicking through any menus. 
Is there any possibility to do this for someone like me without further knowledge of the script-language?

Holger

Answer (score 0):

For tables, I have assumed that you have a spreadsheet with one or more **ranges** of interesting data. 
Yes, you can define a "form" user interface in google-apps-script, create grid widgets for the tables of interest and map the data from the spreadsheet ranges to the widgets. The documentation and examples will take you a fair way along the development path see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_grid. When you have a UI script you can set it to open automatically when the spreadsheet is opened using the triggers feature.

If, however, you are trying to avoid the complexity (for your users) of navigating through a spreadsheet simply to **view** the interesting table data, you could consider creating an html view of the data. The simplest way of doing that is to user Google Sites to define a page and populate the page with the tables using a gadget from the standard library like "Spreadsheet Range Publisher". This avoids writing any script language.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. In fact I want to avoid the the navigation for my users (without any scripting <g>), but I want to display not the table data but a form to type some data in it, so the data is written to the table.